# I have to make Radio button as checked in C#?

Tags: c#, webforms, radio-button

I have to make radio button as checked in code behind in C#.
I tried the below code but this didn't work.

```
RadioButtonList active =(RadioButtonList)editItem.FindControl("radbtnProfileName");
if(valueres.Select(i => i.profile).FirstOrDefault()) //this is the value(column) I am getting from the SP
{
    active.SelectedValue = "Yes";
}
else
{
    active.SelectedValue = "No";
}
```

Comment: `active.Checked=true`?

Comment: Have you tried `active.Selected = true;`

Comment: I tried active.Checked=true & active.Selected = true; but it is saying RadioButtonList does not contain a definition for checked and no extension  method 'checked' accepting the first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButtonList.

Comment: Have you tried `active.SelectedIndex = x;` where `x` is the index of the respective control for yes/no?

Comment: RadiobuttonList isnt even a winforms/wpf control, maybe tag what you're using?

Comment: I tried all these it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Use Forms in Visual Studio in the furture.